# Eclipse Window Builder importing classes

Tags: java, eclipse, class, user-interface, windowbuilder

I'm working on a GUI in Window Builder and I want to import some of the objects I have declared on my main. The GUI is in the same package as my main and 5 classes, 1 parent and 4 child classes. Is this possible to do? As of right now, I'm trying to call my characters for the game I created into the GUI to be displayed when a certain button is pushed.

So far, I tried importing each class into my GUI. That didn't work went into my main and added my GUI by declaring it as a new object followed up by adding   EventQueue.invokeLater and making that visible, but that didn't really work. Any thoughts on how to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

On Window builder Palette, click choose component and search for your class for example

`package.class`. This is the image:-

[image]

Refer to [this](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wb.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fuserinterface%2Fpalette.html).